# Mobile selecting of text inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

If i have an input type=text and am viewing it on a mobile device, if I press inside the input and hold down on the text (let's say it's a url), the entire url won't be selected. Only a single word will be.  I want to be able to easily select the entire text and then copy it.  Is there a way to do this in css or html?  I can select all the text with javascript but then trying to touch down to copy does the same thing, only selects a word.

for instance:

```
<input type="text" value="http://foo.bar">
```

I click in the middle and only "foo" gets selected. I want to select all the text so it's easy to copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    this.select()
});
$('input').click(function() {
    this.focus();this.select()
});
```

Implemented here: http://jsfiddle.net/4XJDW/